# apache multiple name based virtual hosts on different ports on single apache instance

Tags: apache-2.2, virtual-hosting

Is there a way to host apache multiple name based virtual hosts on different ports on single apache instance ?

Say for example default instance listen on port 80

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin alert@example.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs/example
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

now I would like to have on the same instance of apache

```
<VirtualHost *:8088>
    ServerAdmin alert@example.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs/example1
    ServerName example1.com
    ServerAlias www.example1.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example1.com/
    ErrorLog logs/error_log
    CustomLog logs/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will also need to tell Apache itself to listen on the extra ports in /etc/apache2/ports.conf (if you're on a RedHat-based distro, it'll be in /etc/httpd/)

```
...
NameVirtualHost *:81
NameVirtualHost *:85
Listen 81
Listen 85
...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , i got this working by specifying Listen / NameVirtualHost in the same httpd.conf however still can't get to the virtual hostname , i even tried ..
<VirtualHost *:8088> 
     DocumentRoot "/path/to/site2/" 
     ServerName *:8088
</VirtualHost>

Comment: I would recommend using separate vhost configs instead of lumping everything in to httpd.conf.

/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com
/etc/apache2/sites-available/example1.com

then either symlink them to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ or run 
_a2ensite example1.com example2.com_

Did you add the ports into ports.conf?

Also, check Apache2 is listening on 8088 by running _lsof -i :8088_

Comment: wait, did he just say ServerName *:8088 ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Specify the port in both the `NameVirtualHost` directive and in the `<VirtualHost>` directive.